# Regex to find code without linebreak

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

I want to find any code line where a **`}`** is followed by a break and then a /**.

```
    }
    /**
```

I don't want to find code lines where there is a empty line between.

NOT:

```
    }

    /**
```

I find my self unable to write such a regex.
I thought it would be as simple as `}\n\/\*\*` but this didn't work.

I need this to find bad formating in Java Classes with IntelliJ.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/hoCOdF/1

Comment: @0m3r: This doesn't work in IntelliJ. Something is different with the lines. I forked your example to match my case where you can see that it doesn't work: https://regex101.com/r/mB79rn/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have to account for spaces after the new line, do this

```
}\n\h*\/\*\*
```

**`}`** matches the character } literally (case sensitive)
**`\n`** matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
**`\h`** matches any horizontal whitespace character (equal to [[:blank:]])

**Image of the regular expression matching**

[image]

**NOTE**

To find formatting issues within your code there are plugins you can use. Look into http://www.sonarlint.org/.

Comment: As mentioned bellow the other answers, this doesn't work in my case because of space before the comment in the next line.

Comment: @Spen look at my edit, and look at the working example https://regex101.com/r/DDocqN/2

Comment: Your updated answer does work! Thank you. I didn't see that this would work.

Comment: @Spen you can also replace the `.` with a `\h` to match any whitespaces but it wont match if there are characters before `/**`. You're welcome, thanks for the accept, good luck!

Comment: After i accepted your answer you changed it to a regex that doesn't work. Therefore i changed the accepted answers. In the meantime you changed the regex again and now it's working again.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

**`\s*(\}\n\h\s*\/\*{2})`**

***https://regex101.com/r/hoCOdF/3***

> [image]
>
> [image]

**`\}`** matches the character } literally (case sensitive)
**`\n`** matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
**`\/`** matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
**`\*{2}`**
matches the character * literally (case sensitive) - **`{2}`** Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times
**`\h`** matches any horizontal `whitespace` character (equal to **`[[:blank:]]`**)

Comment: As mentioned above, there is a small difference in my case that makes this hard: https://regex101.com/r/mB79rn/1

Comment: @Spen Okay let me try something different

Answer (score 1):

Also include carriage return if your files are created within Windows `}[\n\r]\/\*\*`

Edit : use this one to include space and tabs between breaks and { : 
`}[\n\r]( |\t)+\/\*\*`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex with positive look ahead like this:

```
\}(?=\n[^\n]*\/\*\*)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/DDocqN/3)**

Since you tagged with IntelliJ, below you have a screenshot of the regex working

[image]

Comment: I already did but this doesn't turn up with results neither. I have a class open that has this formating so it should be able to find at least this one, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Spen, I updated the answer and also added an screenshot of it working well

Comment: The difference is that in my case the new line isn't starting with \**: https://regex101.com/r/mB79rn/1

Comment: @Spen, you are using a different regex of what I provided you, I'm using lookarounds. Check the demo link provided in the answer, it doesn't matter if they `}` contains spaces at the beginning

Comment: Oh sorry, the regex in the example was the regex from 0m3r. I just posted this link because of the case where your regex also doesn't match. Here the correct link: https://regex101.com/r/DDocqN/1

Comment: @Spen, in this latest link you are asking something different than your question. My answer is answering your question, in your link your are having a different scenario where you have a new line plus spaces, where in your question you ask for only new lines.

Comment: Yes, i didn't see that this part was important. I have updated my question.

Comment: @Spen, I have updated my answer for your comment, check the 2nd regex

Comment: Yes, this does work :) finally. I was really stuck with this problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Spen, glad to help you

Comment: @Downvoter, any feedback why you didn't like the answer?